# How does this callcc example work?

Tags: functional-programming, callcc

`(callcc (fun k -> k 7)) + 3

(callcc (fun k -> 7)) + 3`

What do each of these evaluate to and why?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is homework. If it's not, just say so and I'll tell you the answer directly.

The way `call/cc` works it to capture the continuation at the point it's called. What that means for these examples, is when you see `call/cc`, replace the whole call with a black box and look at what's left:

```
(call/cc (fun k -> k 7)) + 3
=>
************************ + 3
```

So `+ 3` is what happens with the result of the `call/cc` call. This "what happens next" is the thing that `call/cc` packages up and calls `k`*.

All you need to now is figure out what happens with you call `k` with the value 7.

For the second example, you don't call `k` at all. Since you don't do anything special with `k`, you shouldn't expect `call/cc` to do anything special.

---

Note: The code you give looks like some kind of ML. None of the ML dialects I know have `call/cc`, so if your dialect doesn't either, try downloading [PLT Scheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org) to play with it interactively. The syntax isn't too hard to pick up.

*'continuation' is a slightly nicer way to say "what happens next", although not much nicer.